# fluphenazine read as \xef\xac\x82uphenazine

Tags: python, unicode

When I write

```
>>> st = "Piperazine (perphenazine, ﬂuphenazine)"

>>> st

'Piperazine (perphenazine, \xef\xac\x82uphenazine)'
```

What is happening? why doesn't it do this for any `fl`? How do I avoid this?

It looks \xef\xac\x82 is not, in fact, `fl`. Is there any way to 'translate' this character into fl (as the author intended it), without just excluding it via something like

```
 unicode(st, errors='ignore').encode('ascii')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what is called a "ligature".

In printing, the f and l characters were typeset with a different amount of space between them from what normal pairs of sequential letters used - in fact, the f and l would merge into one character. Other ligatures include "th", "oe", and "st".

That's what you're getting in your input - the "fl" ligature character, UTF-8 encoded. It's a three-byte sequence. I would take minor issue with your assertion that it's "not, in fact `fl`" - it really is, but your input is UTF-8 and not ASCII :-). I'm guessing you pasted from a Word document or an ebook or something that's designed for presentation instead of data fidelity (or perhaps, from the content, it was a LaTeX-generated PDF?).

If you want to handle *this particular case*, you could replace that byte sequence with the ASCII letters "fl". If you want to handle *all such* cases, you will have to use the Unicode Consortium's "UNIDATA" file at: http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt . In that file, there is a column for the "decomposition" of a character. The f-l ligature has the identifier "LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FL". There is, by the way, a Python module for this data file at https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html . You want the "decomposition" function:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> foo = u"ﬂuphenazine"
>>> unicodedata.decomposition(foo[0])
'<compat> 0066 006C'
```

0066 006C is, of course, ASCII 'f' and 'l'.

Be aware that if you're trying to downcast UTF-8 data to ASCII, you're eventually going to have a bad day. There are only 127 ASCII characters, and UTF-8 has millions upon millions of code points. There are many codepoints in UTF-8 that cannot be readily represented as ASCII in a nonconvoluted way - who wants to have some text end up saying "`<TREBLE CLEF> <SNOWMAN> <AIRPLANE> <YELLOW SMILEY FACE>`"?